# putting commas separated values into a new file line by line

Tags: csv

From command line, we are passing multiple values separated by commas such as `sydney,delhi,NY,Russia` as an option. These values are getting stored under `$runTest` in the perl script. Now I want to create a new file under the script with contents of `$runTest` but as line by line. For example:

INPUT (passed values from command line):

```
sydney,delhi,NY,Russia
```

OUTPUT (under new file: myfile):

```
sydney
delhi
NY
Russia
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: my $runTest = 'sydney,delhi,NY,Russia';
open my $out, '>', 'myFile' or die $!;

print {$out} $regsToRun =~ tr/,/\n/r;

Comment: @Aakash: Please put code in your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

In this simple example, it is better to use `split` on a delimiter than `tr` in such case. A few minor points: use snake_case for names instead of CamelCase, and `use autodie` to make `open`, `close`, etc, fatal, without the need to clutter the code with `or die "..."`:

```
use autodie;
my $run_test = 'sydney,delhi,NY,Russia'; 
open my $out, '>', 'myFile'; 
print {$out} map { "$_\n" } split /,/, $run_test; 
close $out;
```

---

**For more robust parsing in general, beyond this simple example, prefer specialized modules, such as [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) or [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) for csv parsing.** Compared to the overly simplistic `split`, `Text::CSV_XS` enables correct input/output of quoted fields, fields containing the delimiter (comma), binary characters, provides error messages and more. Example:

```
use Text::CSV_XS;
use autodie;
open my $out, q{>}, q{myFile}; 
# All of these input strings are parsed correctly, unlike when using "split":
# my $run_test = q{sydney,delhi,NY,Russia};
# my $run_test = q{sydney,delhi,NY,Russia,"field,with,commas"};
my $run_test = q{sydney,delhi,NY,Russia,"field,with,commas","field,with,missing,quote};

# binary => 1 : enable parsing binary characters in quoted fields.
# auto_diag => 1 : print the internal error code and the associated error message to STDERR.
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 } );

if ( $csv->parse( $run_test ) ) {
    print {$out} map { "$_\n" } $csv->fields;
}
else {
    print STDERR q{parse() failed on: }, $csv->error_input, qq{\n};
}
```

Comment: Eventually `split` is going to bite you. For CSV, promote something like `Text::CSV_XS`. Many more people than the OP read the answer and follow the advice.

Comment: Thanks @briandfoy for the suggestion, added this to the answer.